# Unbiased estimator of the $l$-norm of a probability vector

Tags: probability, parameter-estimation

We are given a probability space on $\Omega = [k] = \{1,...,k\}$. Let $p(i)$  be the probability assigned to $i$. These are unknown.

I need, for real $l > 0$, an unbiased estimator for $\sum_{i=1}^k p(i)^l$.  That is, a function $f : \mathbb [k]^n \to [0,1]^k$ such that $E[f(X)] = \sum_{i=1}^n p(i)^l$.

In the case $l=1$, what works is letting $Y_i$ be the number of times that $i$ appears in the given sample vector, and letting $f(X) = \frac 1n[Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n]$. Naturally, since $Y_i$ is binomially distributed, we get our result.

The idea, is to look now for random variables $Z_i : [k]^n \to [0,1]$,probably depending on $Y_i$, such that $E[Z_i] = p(i)^l$. But, $Z_i = Y_i^l$, an obvious candidate, doesn't do the job. Of course, obtaining such $Z_i$  will allow me to use $f(X) = [Z_i]$ as the desired answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n\geq l$,
$$\mathbb E\left[Y_1(Y_1-1)\ldots(Y_1-l+1)\right]$$
$$=\sum_{k=l}^n k(k-1)\ldots(k-l+1) \binom{n}{k} \bigl(p(1)\bigr)^k \bigl(1-p(1)\bigr)^{n-k}$$
$$
=n(n-1)\ldots(n-l+1)\cdot \bigl(p(1)\bigr)^l\cdot\sum_{k-l=0}^{n-l} \binom{n-l}{k-l} \bigl(p(1)\bigr)^{k-l} \bigl(1-p(1)\bigr)^{(n-l)-(k-l)}
$$
$$
=n(n-1)\ldots(n-l+1)\cdot \bigl(p(1)\bigr)^l.
$$
So, 
$$\mathbb E\left[\frac{Y_1(Y_1-1)\ldots(Y_1-l+1)}{n(n-1)\ldots(n-l+1)}\right]=\bigl(p(1)\bigr)^l$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I shall look further into it.

Comment: Yes, it is correct, very nice indeed. But I had a question : what if $l > n$? It is clear that the above does not work. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If $l>n$ then unbiased estimator for $p(i)^l$ does not exist. This is the direct consequence of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra

Comment: Oh, I see the issue! Thank you so much for the answer. An acceptance gladly follows.